# QueueWorker for specific Queues picking random tube

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue

I'm using laravel 5.3 framework and beanstalk as queue driver.

Let's say I've got 10 tubes to push jobs to. I've got three QueueWorkers running by command:

`php artisan queue:work --tries=1 --timeout=600 --queue=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

If I understood correctly the QueueWorker always checks the tubes in the above order (from 1 to 10) if there are any jobs on the tube in ready state. Is there a way to let the Queueworker randomnly pick a tube to get jobs to work on?

Comment: What's  the point to have  10 tubes if the same  worker can handle all of them?

Comment: run  multiple instances with of: `php artisan queue:work --tries=1 --timeout=600 --queue=1`, `php artisan queue:work --tries=1 --timeout=600 --queue=2`, ...

Comment: If tube 1 contains 100 jobs, the QueueWorker will work on those 100 jobs before working on the other tubes. For us, multiple workers working on one tube isn't a benefit. Multiple workers working on random tubes will increase the speed of handling all jobs from all tubes a lot. Offcourse we can start a worker for every tube but that means 5 out of 10 will do nothing at all, most of the time.